# Where is my argument that $\int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}dx=0$ wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$$

I let $u = 1-x^2$, $x = (1-u)^{1/2}$

$du = -2x dx$

$$-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{0} \frac{u^{1/2}}{(1-u)^{1/2}}du = 0$$ because $$\int_{a}^{a} f(x)dx = 0$$

But it isn't zero. Why?????

Comment: Under what conditions can you use u substitution?

Comment: It is not zero because the integrand is strictly positive. **Edit:** And continuous.

Comment: f and g' are continuous.. i see now

Comment: Very closely related question (and my answer): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489577/why-is-it-not-true-that-int-0-pi-sinx-dx-0/1489594#1489594

Comment: @CameronWilliams Duplicates, really.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For $x \in [-1,0)$, you *can't have*
$$
u = 1-x^2 \implies x = (1-u)^{1/2}
$$ thus your change of variable is *not valid* over $[-1,0)$.

You would better write by parity
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}dx=2\int_0^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}dx
$$ then use the given change of variable.

Answer (score 13):

You may only do a u-substitution when it is bijective on your integration domain. You can solve this problem by breaking up your integral into $\int_{-1}^0$ and $\int_0^1,$ and using $x=-(1-u)^{1/2}$on the first integral, and $x=(1-u)^{1/2}$ on the second.